# Eclipse-Plugin Java AST-Scan IJavaProject.getPackageFragments() with closed projects

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I get this:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [SomeProjectMadeByMe does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newJavaModelException(JavaElement.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildren(JavaElement.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:1850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragments(JavaProject.java:1872)
```

when trying to get all package fragments within an IJavaProject, when this project is referencing another project in the workspace and the latter is closed (thus not openable).

How can I skip the fragments from the closed project instead of letting the method throw an exception? Do I have to write my own method?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the [isOpen](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIOpenable.html) method on the package fragment or package fragment root should let you know whether or not you can access it.